# How to verify $(a,b) = (c,d) \implies a = c \wedge b = d$ naively

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

Given set $A, B$, $a\in A, b\in B$, we call

$$(a, b) = \{a, \{a, b\}\}.$$

> How do we show naively that
>   $$(a, b) =(c, d) \Rightarrow a =c , b=d?$$

The proof that I have in mind is the following:

Given $(a, b) = (c, d)$, so

$$\{a, \{a, b\}\} = \{ c,  \{ c, d\}\}.$$

First of all $a \neq \{ a, b\}$, or this will give $a\in a$. Similarly $c\neq \{c, d\}$.

Now $a\in \{c, \{c, d\}\}$ so either $a = c$ or $a= \{c, d\}$.

If the latter is true, then we have

$$ c = \{ a, b\} = \{ \{ c, d\} , b\}$$

This implies

$$c \in \{ c, d\} \in c$$

and it is not allowed. Thus $a=c$. So

$$\{a, b\} = \{c, d\} = \{ a, d\}$$

and from there we can show also $b=d$.

**Question**: This results is stated in p.8 of this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821847872), but they never mention that infinite chain is not allowed. So I was wondering if there is an even more naive way to prove the above assertion.

Comment: It's more usual to use $\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$.

Comment: In the book they are using what I wrote. Will your definition make the proof simpler? @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: @JohnMa Yes, it does simplify the proof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to prove this without using the axiom of regularity.  Indeed, suppose you have a set $a$ such that $a=\{\{a\},a\}$ but $a\neq \{a\}$ (the existence of such a set is consistent with all the axioms of ZFC except regularity; for instance, it follows from Boffa's anti-foundation axiom).  Then $$(a,a)=\{a,\{a\}\}=a$$ and also $$(\{a\},a)=\{\{a\},\{\{a\},a\}\}=\{\{a\},a\}=a$$ so $(a,a)=(\{a\},a)$ even though $a\neq \{a\}$.

Answer (score 2):

If you omit the axiom of foundation/regularity from ZFC, you *cannot* prove this. It is consistent with the rest of the axioms that you can have $(a,b)=(c,d)$ with $a \neq c$ and $b \neq d$.

Comment: So is it true that the Stefan's answer is wrong somewhere, as they did not use the axiom of regularity?

Comment: @JohnMa: Stefan's answer is fine; it's proving that $\{ \{ a \}, \{ a, b \} \}$ satisfies the needed theorem, rather than $\{ a, \{ a, b \} \}$ that you asked about. The former model for ordered pairs doesn't require regularity in the proof; that's why it's "more usual to use" than the latter.

Answer (score 1):

Allow me to define 
$$
\langle a,b \rangle = \{ \{a\}, \{a,b\} \}
$$
and I claim that $\langle a,b \rangle = \langle c,d \rangle \implies a = c \wedge b = d$.

*Proof.* If $X= \{ \{a\}, \{a,b\} \} = \{ \{c\}, \{c,d\} \}$. Then $a$ is the unique element of the unique singleton of $X$ and so is $c$. Therefore we must have $a = c$.

If $a = b$ (or $c = b$), then $X = \{ \{a \} \} = \{ \{c\} \}$ and we must have $c = d$ (or $a = b$) and we are done.

Hence we may assume that $a \neq b$ and $c \neq d$. Now $b$ is the unique element of the unique $2$-element set in $X$ that is not equal to $a =c$ and likewise for $d$. But this implies that $b = d$. Q.E.D.

Comment: A very similar proof works for your definition of $(a,b)$ but there are a couple of additional considerations since, for example, $a$ could happen to have exactly two elements.

Comment: The only axiom I'm using here is extensionality.

Comment: There is no very similar proof that works for the definition of $(a,b)$ in the question, at least not without using the axiom of regularity like OP did.

Comment: @EricWofsey Whenever I say proof with no additional information, I mean proof in $\mathrm{ZFC}$.

Comment: OK, but OP seems to be specifically asking for a proof without using regularity.

Comment: @Eric I didn't get that from OP's question. But sure, if that's the case, I should have been more specific.

Comment: I could have made it more explicit in the question. The book mentions only the axiom of extensionality and leave my assertion as an exercise. Now I have a feeling that it is a typo.